# React Query On Success does not trigger

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm currently having a problem that I can't explain. I work with React, typescript and react query.
The code on which I work is a double modal and when clicking on the refuse button of the second one launches a call via react query then we execute an onSuccess.

If I move the hook call into the first modal the onSuccess fires.
If I move the OnSuccess from the second modal into the hook it works too.

But I don't understand why in this case it doesn't work...
Does anyone have an idea/explanation please?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code below of the first modal

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '../Button'
import SecondModal from '../SecondModal'

interface FirstModalProps {
    isOpen: boolean
    setIsOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
    id?: string
}

const FirstModal = ({ id, isOpen, setIsOpen }: 
FirstModalProps) => {
    const [openRefuse, setOpenRefuse] = React.useState<boolean>(false)

return (
    <>
        <SecondModal isOpen={openRefuse} setIsOpen={setOpenRefuse} id={id} />
        <Button
            onClick={() => {
                setIsOpen(false)
                setOpenRefuse(true)
            }}
            text="refuse"
        />
    </>
)}

export default FirstModal
```

Then the code of the second modal

```
import React from 'react'
import ConfirmModal from '../../../../../shared/styles/modal/confirm'
import useUpdate from '../../hooks/use-update'

interface SecondModalProps {
    isOpen: boolean
    setIsOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
    id?: string
}

const SecondModal = ({ isOpen, setIsOpen, id }: SecondModalProps) => {
const { mutate: update } = useUpdate()

const updateT = () => {
    update(
        {
            id
        },
        {
            onSuccess: () => {
                console.log('OnSuccess trigger')
            }
        }
    )
}

return (
    <ConfirmModal
        close={() => {
            setIsOpen(false)
        }}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        validate={updateT}
    />
)}

export default SecondModal
```

Then the hook

```
import { useMutation } from 'react-query'

interface hookProps {
    id?: string
}

const useUpdate = () => {
const query = async ({ id }: hookProps) => {
    if (!id) return
    return (await myApi.updateTr(id))()
}

return useMutation(query, {
    onError: () => {
        console.log('error')
    }
})}

export default useUpdate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

callbacks passed to the `.mutate` function only execute if the component is still mounted when the request completes. On the contrary, callbacks on `useMutation` are always executed. This is [documented here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations#mutation-side-effects), and I've also written about it [in my blog here](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#some-callbacks-might-not-fire).